# Adding abillity to woocommerce attribute shortcode to open items with same attribute selected

Tags: function, woocommerce, attributes, shortcode

Lets say we have added this shortcode to our website:

```
[products columns="3" attribute="season" terms="warm" orderby="date"]
```

You know it shows all products with attribute "warm", but when we click on each of them, on single product page the "warm attribute" is not selected.

It will be more convenient for user to see that attribute is already selected. How we can do that?

Can we add any function to add something like `?attribute_pa_season=warm` at the end of URLs?

Many thanks for suggestions:)

Comment: Welcome to SO. I've added code formatting to your question to improve readability. You can use the visual editor or Markdown to format code. https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: Thank you. Sorry for that. I'm new contributor.